# Kinect 2 fast handle frames -> low fps rate

Tags: c#, kinect, frame-rate

When I use the example color basics of the kinect 2 and calculate time in millisecond between each image, it's usually around 30ms, but when I change the inner code of the function image event into comment, time between frames are:

```
34,231,32,33,134,32,266,32,33,172,67,166,28,64,33,101,32,33,34,32,32,138,94,32,26
```

and so on (less then 20 fps).

My computer using i7 (8 cures), **total** cpu only 6% only, 8GB memory.. so it's not the problem.

Relevant code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Active Kinect sensor
        /// </summary>
        private KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reader for color frames
        /// </summary>
        private ColorFrameReader colorFrameReader = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Bitmap to display
        /// </summary>
        private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        private string statusText = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            // get the kinectSensor object
            this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

            // open the reader for the color frames
            this.colorFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();

            // wire handler for frame arrival
            this.colorFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_ColorFrameArrived;

            // create the colorFrameDescription from the ColorFrameSource using Bgra format
            FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = this.kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

            // create the bitmap to display
            this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorFrameDescription.Width, colorFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

            // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier
            this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

            // open the sensor
            this.kinectSensor.Open();

            // set the status text
            this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                            : Properties.Resources.NoSensorStatusText;

            // use the window object as the view model in this simple example
            this.DataContext = this;

            // initialize the components (controls) of the window
            this.InitializeComponent();

            sw.Start();
        }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the color frame data arriving from the sensor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();
            // ColorFrame is IDisposable

            // Changed into comment here:

            /*using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if (colorFrame != null)
                {
                    FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;

                    using (KinectBuffer colorBuffer = colorFrame.LockRawImageBuffer())
                    {
                        this.colorBitmap.Lock();

                        // verify data and write the new color frame data to the display bitmap
                        if ((colorFrameDescription.Width == this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth) && (colorFrameDescription.Height == this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight))
                        {
                            colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToIntPtr(
                                this.colorBitmap.BackBuffer,
                                (uint)(colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * 4),
                                ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

                            this.colorBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight));
                        }

                        this.colorBitmap.Unlock();
                    }
                }
            }*/
        }
    }
```

Why that and how to solve it?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Console.WriteLine is not made for high perf code. Try adding a counter and print out only every 10th frame with if( frameCounter++ % 10 == 0) Console.WriteLine

Comment: WriteLine is not part of the time calculation and used both cases, I check the time between frames (should be ~30ms) and only then I print it, and after print restart the time, please see my answer that need "spend" enough time to get next frame at time.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that if you comment the function, you're not calling e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame(), and it leaves the frames on a queue. I can't try it now, please check that yourself. Try leaving only the call to e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame() (and the corresponding call to .Dispose()) uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

When I "spend" enough time on this function it work perfect like:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000000; i++);
```

I don't remember if I used loop of 1 mil or 10 mil iterations (and it's depend the computer), but after use that I get almost always frame every 30ms.

It's look like a bug of Microsoft on kinect 2, their last sdk release - 2.0 (and it's their first).

Pay attention: Using `thread.sleap` wouldn't fix it.

So right now the solution (but very bad) is to check run time (if it too fast) and spend time if needed.